# IBM Cloud Function: Rename Action

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

How can I rename a IBM Cloud function action?

My current course of action is to delete the action and redeploy it under a new name.

I haven't found anything in the [Cloud Functions CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-cli-plugin-functions-cli) or in the functions website that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't rename an action at the moment.

What you can do for now is, like you said, delete the action and redeploy it under another name.